# Phonegap local build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to setup phonegap build locally. I am wondering if I use http://build.phonegap.com, splashscreen and icons etc. are visible for my app.

However if I try to build it locally there is default phonegap icon and no splash screen (i.e. blank screen).

I also have correctly extracted icons and splash screen in res folder under www directory.

I already have those plugins added locally using "phonegap local plugin add " command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for the moment if you add the platform and then change the resources in www folder, the resources are not updated in the platform folder.

You have to update the resources directly in the platform folders.

For android it would be in platforms/android/res/ followed with the different drawable folders depending on the resolution.